# Controller action not grabbing file from view when attempting to upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, file-upload

I am trying to upload a .csv file into an SQL database, but the controller action does not seem to be grabbing the file at all. Check out the code, I must be missing a piece:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadValidationTable", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table style="margin-top: 150px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="csvFile">Filename:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="csvFile" id="csvFile"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadValidationTable(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile)
    {
        var inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
             SeparatorChar = ',',
             FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
        };
        var cc = new CsvContext();
        var filePath = uploadFile(csvFile.InputStream);
        var model = cc.Read<OutstandingCreditCsv>(filePath, inputFileDescription);

        try
        {
            var entity = new OutstandingCreditCsv();

            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                entity.PoNumber = item.PoNumber;
                entity.CreditInvoiceDate = item.CreditInvoiceDate;
                entity.CreditInvoiceNumber = item.CreditInvoiceNumber;
                entity.CreditInvoiceAmount = item.CreditInvoiceAmount;

            }
        }
        catch(LINQtoCSVException ex)
        {

        }

        return Json(model, "text/json");
    }
```

csvFile is just appearing as null, no clue what could be going on since it is named in the view and I have the post method surrounding it. It makes it down until `var filePath = uploadFile(csvFile.InputStream);` and then breaks since the method is trying to pass a null value. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this when trying to upload files into db using MVC a while back, I was using scaffolded views (so it also passed back an object with the form), so it might be a bit different.

In your HTML.BeginForm() call you'll need to add the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadValidationTable", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
```

Comment: Well as I was confirming the syntax it was answered... 3 times. Go me!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your `<form>`

```
using (Html.BeginForm("UploadValidationTable", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                             new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your form declaration. Try adding  enctype = "multipart/form-data" to your form declaration.

`@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadValidationTable", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to the form declaration:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadValidationTable", "Home", null,FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =   "multipart/form-data" }))
```